# Connecting link item to content div id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I'm attempting to create a simple, multi-tabbed navigation that utilizes a single web page.  I have my content laid out as so:

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul><!--/#nav-->

<div id="content-box">
    <div id="tab1">
        <!--content from tab1-->
    </div><!--/#tab1-->

    <div id="tab2">
        <!--content from tab2-->
    </div><!--/#tab2-->

    <div id="tab3">
        <!--content from tab3-->
    </div><!--/#tab3-->

</div><!--/#content-box-->
```

jQuery:

```
$("#nav li").on("click", function(event){
        $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#content-box").children().hide();
    });
```

My problem is that I don't know how to link the `li` with class `active` to the corresponding `div`.  All of my tab divs are set to hidden, and I have a class called `.activeSlide` which turns sets `visibility: visible`.

Comment: Use the [JQueryUI Tab function](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use html 5 `data` attributes to link the div

**html**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li data-content="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li data-content="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  <li data-content="tab3" class="active">Tab 3</li>
</ul><!--/#nav-->
```

**jquery**

```
$("#nav li").on("click", function(event){
    $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#content-box").children().hide();
    $('#'+ $(this).data('content')).show(); 
    //OR
    $("#content-box").children().removeClass('activeSlide');
    $('#'+ $(this).data('content')).addClass('activeSlide');
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/P5UGt/1/)

**updated**

add this in ready function

```
 $(document).ready(){
     $("#content-box").children().hide();
    $("#nav li").on("click", function(event){
      ...... //above function goes here
    });
  
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5UGt/2/)

however i recommned you to use [jquery ui tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) instead of reinventing the wheel... :)

Comment: I was writing an answer like this :-) nice one

Comment: upon clicking a second tab, wouldn't everything be hidden?  data element is good to know about though, thanks!

Comment: @mikey thanks... u are right... damn!!!! i think i need to go for a coffee now.. :)..anyways updated.. thanks again

Comment: @bipen - ha I just finished my coffee that is the only reason I saw it ;)

Comment: @bipen this works, but it shows everything when the page is first loaded.  how would I go about showing just that data in tab1 upon initial load?  Thanks for the answer so far though!

Comment: updated check it out... see the updated part..anyways welcome gald it helped

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your click event:

```
$('#' + $('a', this).attr('href')).show();
```

I would caution, if you're planning to have a lot of content on a single web page, you may want to consider a way for users to *bookmark* certain content, which the above design alone would make quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this,

*HTML*

Remove the id tab1, tab2, tab3. Place class "tab instead".

Like,

```
<div class="tab">
```

instead of, id="tab1" & "tab2" & "tab3"

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
$("#nav li")
    .live("click", function(event){
            var _index = $(this).index();
            $(".tab").hide();
            $(".tab:eq("+_index+")").show();

            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
     });
```